# ¿Como hago una función en sql server para saber si ya existe el registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla donde relaciono Autores y Libros como se ve abajo, lo que quiero es que al momento de intentar insertar una nueva relación antes revise si ya existe dicha relación y si ya existe regrese un mensaje, bueno el problema no es la programación mi problema es que no se como hacer una función en sql que me regrese ya sea un bool o un 1 o 0 para saber si existe o no, la finalidad de que la función sea en sql es porque en dapper solo mando el script que se ejecutara y me debería de regresar el valor que quiero ya con eso lo pudiera comparar dentro del programa. Si no me explique bien favor de decirme estaré al pendiente.
Finalmente quiero una función o un SP que me diga si ya existe o no la relación.
No tengo código ya que no he encontrado algún ejemplo que pudiera entender para hacer lo que quiero.

[image: Esta es mi tabla]

Comment: ¿Por qué no crear un CONSTRAINT y evitar la posibilidad de insertar duplicados?

Comment: La verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento si me pudieras decir como funciona estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en lo que requieres específicamente, el obtener una respuesta para saber si ya existe la relación se puede hacer utilizando procedimientos almacenados.

```sql
CREATE PROC verificarInsertRelacion @idAutor INT, @idLibro INT
AS


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM relaciones 
           WHERE idAutor = @idAutor AND idLibro = @idLibro ) 
BEGIN
 SELECT 1 Resultado 
END
ELSE BEGIN 
 SELECT 0 Resultado
END
```

### Caso de existencia de relación

Se prueba con la siguiente consulta:

```sql
EXEC verificarInsertRelacion 28,13
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

| Resultado |
| --- |
| 1 |

### Caso de NO existencia de relación

Se prueba con la siguiente consulta:

```sql
EXEC verificarInsertRelacion 282,131
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

| Resultado |
| --- |
| 0 |

Luego de ello, puedes almacenar ese 1 o 0 en una variable para poder proceder a usar otro procedimiento almacenado que sea el de insertar la relación nueva.

> Te dejo el [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d46009dc8c63decc036efc9f21af3d4f) resuelto paso por paso.

Comment: Eso no es una función. Es importante diferenciar entre funciones y procedimientos almacenados, en especial la forma de usarlos. Esa era la primer pregunta que hacía cuando hacía entrevistas técnicas de SQL.

Comment: Hay que leer compañero antes de comentar. El compañero que pregunta pide un SP o función, es por ello que he realizado un SP. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho, Luis Cazares me podrías decir la diferencia que tienen para poder seguir aprendiendo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Un procedimiento almacenado es una estructura de código que realiza una operación o conjunto de operaciones. Las operaciones pueden ser de consulta, de modificación de datos, modificación de estructura de la base de datos o alguna otra opción que permita el lenguaje. Las funciones tienen la finalidad de regresar un valor (eso es una constante en cualquier lenguaje y no solo en SQL). El valor de una función puede ser de cualquier tipo incluyendo el tipo tabla, pero siempre será uno solo pero pueden ser llamadas múltiples veces en una instrucción según el número de filas.

Answer (score 0):

no se si te sirva algo como esto:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TABLA(Atributo1, Atributo2, Atributo3)
   VALUES (VALOR1, VALOR2, VALOR3)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM AUTORES 
                   WHERE ...
                   AND ...
END
```

no pude especificar más por que no pusiste los campos de tus tablas o algún query de referencia, aun así espero que esto ayude de alguna forma

Comment: Los campos de la tabla solo son el Id como llave primary auto incrementable el IdAutor que es un valor foráneo, el IdLibro que de igual forma es un valor foráneo, y lo que le llegaría a la función seria solo los ids del auto y libro, lo que quiero es que la función busque si un registro tiene los mismo ids y dependiendo eso regrese algo, se puede ver en el registro 9 y 10 que tienen los mismo valores y eso es lo que quiero evitar.